# How to work with Tensorflow on Android platform?

Tags: android, tensorflow

Google has made the TENSORFLOW open source for developers..

Is there any way out for using this on android?

The link is here [TensorFlow](http://tensorflow.org).

I would love to have some directions to work on this API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The TensorFlow source repository includes an Android example application, with [some documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/README.md).

The Android example includes a pre-trained model for image classification, and uses this to classify images captured by the camera. Typically you would build and train a model using the Python API; generate a serialised version of the model as a GraphDef protocol buffer (and possibly a checkpoint of the model parameters); and then load that and run inference steps using the C++ API.

Comment: thank you @mrry.. Is this API like TESSERACT, in terms of building, compiling and running it using C++ (NDK)?

Comment: Is is necessary to work with Python API, to train my android model of tensorflow? Because I don't know coding in python platform.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tesseract, so can't speak to any comparisons. Also it isn't strictly necessary to *train* your model using the Python API (as the C++ API is also available) but the majority of libraries for TensorFlow (gradients, RNNs, etc.) are currently written in Python, so that API is often easier to use.

Comment: Thank you for better deep involvement, but being new to android, how can I train python with android? How can I make setup of it? Same as NDK or any other way is there to train it!?